# Trouble parsing JSON Data

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON data from a webservice:

```
 {"zip_codes":[{"zip_code":"36451","distance":0,"city":"Grove    Hill","state":"AL"},   {"zip_code":"36446","distance":8.031,"city":"Fulton","state":"AL"}]}
```

I am using the Newtonsoft.Json Library for .Net and trying to parse the above string for the cities. I keep getting an error.

```
public List<string> getZipCodesWithinRadius(string zipCode, string radius)
        {
            List<string> l = new List<string>();

            string apiKey = @"----";
            string apiFormat = @"radius.json";
            string baseUrl = @"http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/";

            string url = baseUrl + apiKey + @"/" + apiFormat + @"/" + zipCode + @"/" + radius + @"/mile";


            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            Stream stream = client.OpenRead(@"http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/uOrUEaRSt9KTqO0OuIFXxwH0uP7uX6AsU2mzcesGncAN1BCvjhtQNbRi0YNX4oqZ/radius.json/36451/10/mile");

            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);

            List<ZipCode> ll = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ZipCode>>(rdr.Read().ToString());


            foreach (ZipCode z in ll)
            {
                l.Add(z.city);
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Causes the following error:

```
Error converting value 123 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Petrologic.Tools.ZipCode]'. Path '', line 1, position 3.
```

Here is my object:

```
 public class ZipCode
    {
        public ZipCode() { }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="zip_code")]
        public string zip_code { get; set; }
         [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "distance")]
        public double distance { get; set; }
         [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city")]
        public string city { get; set; }
         [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
        public string state { get; set; }
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: `rdr.Read()` only reads one character. You probably want to use `ReadToEnd()`. But it still won't work, you may want  a `ZipCodes` class that has a property that is a list of `ZipCode` and deserialize into that type. And don't post  your api key publicly.

Answer (score 2):

First, go to http://json2csharp.com/ and post your JSON there, and get back the following c# classes:

```
public class ZipCode
{
    public string zip_code { get; set; }
    public double distance { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ZipCode> zip_codes { get; set; }
}
```

Next, rather than streaming the JSON into a string then deserializing the string, you can deserialize from the stream directly.

Finally, be sure to wrap all disposables in a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Thus:

```
    public List<string> getZipCodesWithinRadius(string zipCode, string radius)
    {
        List<string> zipCodes = new List<string>();

        string apiKey = @"---REMOVED FROM ANSWER---";
        string apiFormat = @"radius.json";
        string baseUrl = @"http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/";

        string url = baseUrl + apiKey + @"/" + apiFormat + @"/" + zipCode + @"/" + radius + @"/mile";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var root = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
            if (root != null)
            {
                foreach (ZipCode z in root.zip_codes)
                {
                    zipCodes.Add(z.city);
                }
            }
        }
        return zipCodes;
    }
```

By the way, you're not actually passing the input arguments to your service -- the URL used is hardcoded.  Is thus just test code?  It seems so, because if I do `client.OpenRead(url)` then everything works as expected.

Also by the way, shouldn't your method be called `getCitiesWithinRadius()`?  It's returning cities not zip codes after all.  Also, for cities with more than one zip code, it returns duplicated city names.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error since your *root object* is not a list/array. (Your *root object* has a property *zip_codes* which returns a list of zip codes)

You can get your list simply by:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var json = client.DownloadString(url);
    List<ZipCode> ll = JObject.Parse(json)["zip_codes"].ToObject<List<ZipCode>>();
}
```